# How to read the link content only once in Voiceover? (Firefox only)

Tags: list, firefox, hyperlink, wai-aria, voiceover

Why is this text being read twice by Firefox Voiceover? And how make it read it once? (keep the list markup)

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/something">This text is duplicated in Voiceover</a>
        <span class="">Some description</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsbin.com/duseqi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

What type of device does this occur on (MacBook, iPad, iPhone, etc)?

I think this could deal with how you are navigating through the text, and/or if it is a block-level link.  In VoiceOver on Mac, if you are navigating using the tab key, block-level link text is repeated.  According to [this article](http://simplyaccessible.com/article/html5-block-links/), "The behavior depends on the combination of screen reader, browser and navigation mode."

Though your example doesn't include this, VO could repeat the text if you have an `aria-label` attribute present, too.

In your actual markup, do you have any other elements within the anchor tag?  If so, maybe switching the structure of those block-level elements could help avoid the duplication.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

VoiceOver repeats the text for link text twice in both Chrome and Firefox when the link is nested inside a list. It doesn't do this in Safari. I don't think it's an issue with your markup, it's an issue with how VO works with the browser.

I have found some other weird behaviours in Chrome, like not announcing the structure for headings (e.g. reading "My Amazing Heading" instead of "Heading level two, My Amazing Heading") when the content is inside of a div with the "main" ARIA landmark role, which also works fine in Safari.

Comment: Here's my 2 cents on this one. I've encountered the following: whitespace in your source code (like when conditional statements insert whitespace) makes it read twice to four times. <fieldset> without a <legend>, or, with a <legend> and no text makes it read twice.  CSS display: inline-block...yes. this actually made VoiceOver choke in some situations for Chrome.